# Angular 11 get any param from object is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Whatever I do, no matter how I change the code, I cannot get hostelid.
The problem with method `deleteHostel`.
Model:

```
export class Hostel {
    hostelid: string;
    name: string;
    location: string;
    phone?: string;    
    employees?: Array<Employee>;
}
```

Service:

```
export class HostelService {
     getHostels(): Observable<Hostel[]>
    {
      return this.http.get<Hostel[]>(`${this.apiUrl}api/Hostels/`);
    }   
    deleteHostel(id: string): Observable<any>
    {
      return this.http.delete(`${this.apiUrl}api/Hostels/${id}`);
    }
}
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap['id'];
    this.isAddMode = !this.id;
    this.loadHostels();
    if (!this.isAddMode) {
      this.hostelService.getHostelById(this.id)
          .pipe(first())
          .subscribe( hostel => {this.hostel = hostel});
    }
    else {
      this.hostel = new Hostel();
      let newid = Guid.New() as string;
      this.hostel.hostelid = newid;
    }
  }
loadHostels(): void
  {
    this.hostelService.getHostels().subscribe((data:Hostel[])=> {this.hostels = data});    
  }
deleteHostel(id: number):void{    
    let hostel = this.hostels[id];
    let hostelid = hostel.hostelid;
    let res = this.hostelService.deleteHostel(hostelid).subscribe( response => {
      this.hostels.forEach((item, index) => {
      if(item.hostelid === hostelid){ 
        this.hostels.splice(index,1);
      }
    }); },
    err => {
      this.notifSrv.openSnackBar('error');
    });
    
  }
```

html:

```
<mat-list *ngIf="hostels">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of hostels; last as last; let index = index;">
                <h3 matSubheader>{{item.name}} 
                    <button mat-icon-button color="warn" aria-label="delete" (click)="deleteHostel(index)">
                        <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                    <button mat-icon-button color="accent" aria-label="edit" (click)="updateHostel(index)">
                        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </h3>
                <mat-list-item>                    
                <div> <span><span *ngIf="item.phone">{{item.phone}}</span>
                    &nbsp;{{item.location}}</span>   
                </div>                 
                </mat-list-item>
                <mat-divider *ngIf="!last"></mat-divider>
            </ng-container>               
        </mat-list>
```

Index return normal data - `0,1,2`.

But `hostelid` always is `undefined`.

If I change deleteHostel parameter to object param (string), in html

```
(click)="deleteHostel(item.hostelid)
```

and in component

```
deleteHostel(id: string)
```

`id` is `undefined`.
If I change deleteHostel parameter to object , in html

```
(click)="deleteHostel(item)
```

and in component

```
deleteHostel(item: Hostel)
```

`item` is `undefined`.

I googled a lot and tried a lot of options but nothing worked.

## Update: console log

If I change deleteHostel parameter to object , in html

```
(click)="deleteHostel(item)
```

and in component

```
deleteHostel(hostel: Hostel)
{
 console.log(hostel); <--{hostelId: "4f8be387-bbb0-4bfa-8217-09edca45f7ee", name: "test2", location: "test2", phone: null, employees: null}
 console.log(hostel.hostelid); <-- undefined
}
```

I have vague doubts about hostelId in object, and hostelid in class,  how can this be? because the type is the same.

Comment: put any for your param and then console it . check whether the item has hostelid or not

Comment: added what you asked

Comment: Javascript property names are case sensitive, did you try using `hostel.hostelId`?

Comment: how can i get `hostelId` if `hostelid: string;`? and also there is a type conversion in the service?

Comment: Typo mistake it's not hostelid it hostelID. Change it then it will work

Comment: it worked, but you will either have to either not convert to type Hostel, put type any in parameter in method, or change field in class Hostel to `hostelID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript property names are case sensitive. Seems like the ID in your model `Hostel` was defined with the incorrect casing. It should be:

```
export interface Hostel {
  hostelId: string;
  // your other properties
}
```

Don't forget to rename the property in your delete function as well:

```
deleteHostel(hostel: Hostel) {
 console.log(hostel.hostelId);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the reasons and how it works, but it works

Comment: @TheZodchiy as I stated in my answer, the problem is case sensitivity. The upper and lower case of the property names need to be the same.

Comment: the problem is clear. The question is why, after all the conversions to the type, the field with the name HostelId, which left net core, convert H->h, but dont convert I -> i?